# Como ejecutar un codigo php cuando se abre una pagina web

Tags: php, html5

Como puedo hacer que al abrir mi pagina web.html se ejecute un archivo .php, dejo el archivo php que estoy ocupando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Notificaciones web</title>
  <script src="js/push.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
echo '<script>
Push.create("descripcion",{
body: "descripcion 2",
icon: "img/logo.png",
timeout: 4000,
onClick: function () {
window.location="https://www.google.cl/";
this.close();
}
});
</script>';
?>
</body>

</html>
```

---

El código está completo, es el PHP de `webpush`, la verdad mi diseño web está en HTML es decir tengo un `index.html` que es el que se abre al abrir mi sitio web, lo que necesito es que al cargar mi sitio web se ejecute este php, ya que es una notificación `webpush`.

Comment: El servidor puede interpretar una extensión `html` y ejecutar código `PHP` en ella , pero sería configuración adicional,  para empezar  lo recomendable sería cambiar la extensión al archivo  a  `.php` , luego ver posibles errores.

Comment: Es una notificacion webpush que te notifica al abrir la pagina. ¿Como lograria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

solo debes cambiar la extension de tu archivo ".html" a ".php" y luego llamar a tu página desde el navegador "'Ubicación del archivo en el servidor'/web.php"